# Error while using backtrace() function in c++?

Tags: c++, linux

I have to get the backtrace in c++ function and store it into a string as follows:

```
string myFunction()
{
     void *array[5002];
    // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
    size_t size = backtrace(array, 5000);
    char** trace = backtrace_symbols(array, size);
    string stackTrace;
    for(size_t index=0; index<size; ++index)
    {
         stackTrace += trace[index];
    }
 return stackTrace;
}
```

with above use of code i am getting memory fault.
backtrace with gdb of above error is follows

```
?? () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
0x000000359be08934 in _Unwind_Backtrace () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
0x00000035976e6358 in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00002aaaab7afaec in (anonymous namespace)::myFunction() at fileName.cpp
```

Any sugestion to resolve this?
Thanks in Advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `-rdynamic` compiler flag to gcc/g++:

```
g++ -rdynamic -Wall -o file.bin file.cpp
```

Comment: I tried using above flag but i get the same error. One more thing is that errors given in above question is only when the code is debug build other wise it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I would clear with `memset(array, 0, sizeof (array))` the `array` before calling `backtrace`. And I would make it a bit smaller: 5000 frames is really deep.

And `backtrace` probably don't work (at least on 32 bits system) for code compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer` optimization flag to `gcc`.

Comment: Thanks Basile, I tried using memset() but it cant remove the memeory fault. any another oprion for this?

Comment: Arrays can be initialized directly, no need to call `memset`: `void *array[5002] = {};`.